# Cannot Restore Geometry Backup MySQL 5.7 Error

Tags: mysql, geometry

I've been upgrading a website from Mysql `5.6` to `5.7`. When restoring a backup from `mysqldump`, which has worked for 10 years (unchanged) under Mysql 5.1-5.6, it no longer works under MySQL `5.7`.

Specifically, the first row of geometry data fails the restore:

```
ERROR 1416 (22003) at line 1580 Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

So, this **is valid geometry**, but not any more.

Remedies attempted:

- Switch mysqldump to `--hex-blob`
- Try using `astext( <some geometry> )` before importing
- Tired hand loading various geometry rows from the backup, all fail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `MySQL 5.7` is more strict in Geometry types than `MySQL 5.6`. As such, data that **was valid** in 5.6 is now **invalid in 5.7**.

This was the fix to [MySQL Bug #76337](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76337), in release [MySQL 5.7.8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-8.html#mysqld-5-7-8-spatial-support).

In this case, a `LINESTRING` was being stored in a column of type `POINT`. This worked for nearly a decade, but no more. Changing the column to type `LINESTRING` fixed the above loading error.

```
-- The Fix - run on MySQL 5.6 database before Upgrade/Export
ALTER TABLE routes MODIFY COLUMN route_path LINESTRING;
```

**Other Failure Modes**

This bug also manifest on geometric columns where they were able to persist NULL geometries (but not being officially NULL). MySQL `IS NULL` would say not null, but `asText( myGeo )` returned `NULL` under **MySQL 5.7**. Exporting these to a string in MySQL 5.6 returned `''`, empty string. Thus the `''` geometry output from 5.6 was and invalid input for 5.7.

The fix was to null these out.

```
-- Convert NULL geometries to actual NULL's
UPDATE myTable SET myGeo = NULL WHERE asText(myGeo) IS NULL;
```

Comment: I am having this exact problem! I just can't solve it! I have even scaled it back to 1 record so I know that it is POINT data and I know that it is not null.

Comment: asText on 5.6 produces 'POINT(54.89731 -12.884215)', the field type is POINT in both 5.6 and 5.7. But something happens in the mysqldump

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea - 2 years later! what about `ST_IsEmpty`. It will return '1' if the geometry value is invalid or NULL if it is null. 0 if it is valid.